# .mov file choppy when played back in premiere pro cc

Tags: premiere

I made a screen recording using quicktime, but when I import the video into premier pro cc, the playback is choppy.  In on part of the video I have an object that fades in, when this is viewed in quicktime the fade is very gradual and smooth, but in premiere pro it is choppy as if I only get every other frame of the fade.

Comment: Please post some details about the .mov and the Premiere project, including frame rates etc.

Answer (score 3):

This could be a result of a very high resolution video and a slow computer. Try rendering the footage and see if it is still choppy

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely related to glitchiness in the old embedded Quicktime player that was kind of hacked in to 64 bit Premiere.  It can sometimes result in the Quicktime engine grinding to a halt and even completely freeze Premiere.  This is due to the lack of 64 bit support provided for Quicktime for Windows by Apple.  I believe we have another answer that covers it in more detail, but I couldn't find it at the moment.

Either way, the best work around is generally to move the data stream out of the MOV container and move it in to a container that doesn't use the 32 bit Quicktime playback engine if you have problems.  (Not every file seems to have problems for some reason.)

Answer (score 0):

Premiere commonly has issues working with .mov files.  I suggest converting it to an .mp4 file.  You can rename individual files with this extension.  Alternatively, you can use this Python script to convert many files: https://github.com/lys0l/movBaker

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. I imported .MOVs created on a Windows platform into Adobe Premiere Pro on a Mac platform. I tried to create .MP4s using this embedded source. The video had horrible stuttering and was unusable. What ultimately worked for me was opening the .MOV in Quicktime on the Mac, then saving it as a .MOV on the Mac, then using Adobe Media Encoder to convert it to a .MP4, then import it into Adobe Premiere. Painful.

You might be able to skip one or more of these steps. It may not be necessary to convert to .MP4 - YMMV.

Answer (score -2):

I found a way to fix this problem if you are here today and accidentally or unknowingly recorded using hevc or having trouble with playback .mov

Download reNamer by den4b and try replacing the .mov file with .m4a (note: .m4a not .mp4) i tried other file format like flv, avi none worked with Premiere

Its been almost 5 years Adobe!

Hope it works for you :)